# vgextend fail on Couldn't create temporary archive name

Tags: linux, rhel, lvm

we add anew virtual disk as sdb ( from the vcenter )
in order to increase the /var partition

we have redhat version 7.5

so after we add the disk we get

```
 pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg00 lvm2 a--  <39.51g 60.00m
  /dev/sdb        lvm2 ---   80.00g 80.00g
```

now  we initialize a disk or partition

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb
```

now we want to add this to volume group vg00

```
vgextend vg00 /dev/sdb
  Couldn't create temporary archive name.
```

why we get " Couldn't create temporary archive name. "

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
why we get " Couldn't create temporary archive name. "
```

Most likely because your root partition is full.

Try clearing out some files in the root (`/`) partition before running `vgextend`.

Comment: This worked fpr me. My root partition was full.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command and I hope this will get resolved your issue:

```
lvextend -An -r -L +10G /dev/mapper/root
```